# How to solve MODULE_NOT_FOUND error? requestPath: 'concat-map'

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am new to react and I'm having this issue where I'm unable to create a new React app. It worked before I reset my PC. But after I reinstalled windows its not working anymore. I'm providing a screenshot of the error message. Can someone help me out with the issue?

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:444
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\concat-map\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:436:19)
at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:678:18)
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\brace-expansion\index.js:1:17)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
path: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\concat-map\package.json',
requestPath: 'concat-map'
}

Node.js v18.16.0

P.S. I have already tried several past solutions provided on stackoverflow but nothing seems to be working. I also reinstalled node few time, updated npm to 9.7.1 as well as updated the tar package.[The error message I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5hBD.png)